# evil, end of line in elisp mode, is hard to execute eval-last-sexp

Tags: evil

(setq a "3")

If I want to evaluate the line, I'd go to the end of line and do `(eval-last-sexp)`
But in evil mode, the last sexp is "3" not the expression.

I can go to the next line and execute the command, but wonder if there's other way

- edit

So this is.. very hard problem

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/2525

- edit 2

spacemacs seems to handle it by artificially moving eol at the time of evaluation

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/dffa67a7e1f4b9c16f4a9397c7c468d2fe7a975f/layers/%2Blang/common-lisp/funcs.el#L4

although this doesn't solve going back by sexp as commented in the issue, it solves the elisp evaluation problem.

I ended up enabling the `evil-move-byond-eol` because of the backward-sexp and such. what is the most annoying thing setting the eol value?

Comment: If you're in Spacemacs, you can try `spacemacs/eval-current-form-sp`.  It's bound to `, e c`.

Comment: You could check out the variable `evil-move-beyond-eol`. However, although it is a little annoying, personally I just switch to insert state with `A` before doing the eval-last-sexp (or use @g-gundam's suggestion, well `C-M-x` without Spacemacs, whenever possible).

Comment: edited the op. thank you for the answers

Comment: I ended up enabling the `evil-move-byond-eol` because of the `backward-sexp` and such. what is the most annoying thing setting the eol value?